# why do you add a s with some verbs in the 2nd person singular?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know why you write a s with the 2nd person singular.
Like: What gives you wings?

thanks in advance.
Simone

Comment: _What_ is the subject of that sentence, and it is 3rd person singular. _You_ is the _indirect object_ which does _not_ influence the verb (_wings_ is the _direct object_). Compare _I give him a book_ or _You give her a pencil_ - in both cases the verb does not get an -s even though _he_ and _she_ are in the sentence as indirect objects (in the form of _him_ and _her_).

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please see also: [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the verb is not a second person singular. Rather, "what" is the subject. "What" designates a third person singular present (like he, she, or it) and, therefore, is conjugated with an -s.
MThis isn't a true example of a second person singular present verb ending in -s.

There are a few exceptions, like "discuss," "bus," "kiss," and others. These exceptions, however, are trivial, because the second person singular present doesn't change the infinitive other than removing "to."

Comment: Maybe you _discuss_ some exceptions? ;)

Comment: @oerkelens I'd love to, but I can't think of any. Do you have any in mind?

Comment: Apart from the one in my comment I can't think of any (well, there is _cuss_, very similar to the one I mentioned).